# Pooling samples that have no difference in design: asymptotic properties

Tags: mean, small-sample, central-limit-theorem, controlling-for-a-variable

Say I conduct a study and assign participants to one of two arms, but both are identical in design. The only real difference is the label assigned to the group, call them $X$ and $Y$. 
We assume that members from either sample are drawn from the same population.  The baseline data for each group are collected for each of the $N_X$  and $N_Y$ participants in either group respectively:

1. $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{N_X}$ from Control 1
2. $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_{N_Y}$ from Control 2

Does:

1. $\mu_X - \mu_Y \to 0$ as $N_X \to \infty, N_Y \to \infty$ ?
2. $\mu_X - \mu_Y \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ for some $\sigma$

Comment: I don't know what "A/A" means. You speak of both groups as "control". Do you mean to say that you have two control groups that receive the exact same treatment? Then you can rightfully expect them to display very similar results. But I must say I don't understand the purpose of this. Probably you mean that one group is the treatment group and one is the control. Then they should differ in the variable you measure, if the treatment has any effect on it. If not, then the treatment is ineffective.

Comment: @AdamO -- no I mean both are control -- I think some folks use that to calibrate methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the randomization assumption is met, and there is in fact no difference in design between the two groups, the samples could be pooled. However, those assumptions could never be checked in practice. When confronted with the issue, the participants should be analyzed as intent-to-treat: meaning you intended for these participants to be members of two different groups, and they should be left that way.

As to the asymptotic 0 mean with normal distribution: yes, this is a basic result of the CLT. The pooled variance estimator could be calculated using a precision weighted combination of the intergroup variances when the samples are mutually independent.